# Understanding string generation of double vs single quotes

Tags: python, string, text, double-quotes, single-quotes

I'm trying to understand why sometimes double quotes are being generated vs single quotes for my list creation function. I have a function that I've used on multiple text files and normally the output is a list with single quotes, but now double quotes are generated (when I need single).

Would someone be able to help me understand why double quotes might be generated here and/or a way to just force the single quotes?

```
for below structure is :
string_text is str
text_list is list
list_text is list
```

```
def view(string_text):
   text_list = []
   for t in list_text:
       text_list.append(string_text + """   more text """ + t + 
                        """ more text """)
   return text_list
text_list = view(string_text)
```

The append is specific to my use case, but you get the idea. Double quotes are generated for text_list.

```
list_text sample = ['a','b','c']
```

Comment: Where do the double quotes pop up? Can you provide an example of what is in `list_text`?

Comment: yes, edited the question

Comment: What is `string_text is str` `text_list is list` `list_text is list` supposed to do in your code?

Comment: Also, it seems that you are creating a SQL query by concatenating strings, be wary of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @glglgl I've broken this out, trying to show structure for what is used in function

Comment: @Pietro I'm aware of SQL injection

Comment: You use `string_text` as an argument to the call to `view`, but at that point that variable is undefined. Is the argument supposed to be `list_text`?

Comment: When I run the example I get single quotes. It should not make a difference, but may I ask why you use docstring triple-double quotes for your strings?

Comment: @Keine_Eule hm, I normally get single quotes and at a loss for why double is occuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's turn your code into something which can directly be pasted into a python console window:

```
def view(string_text):
    text_list = []
    for t in list_text:
        text_list.append(string_text + """   more text """ + t +
                         """ more text """)
    return text_list

list_text = ['a', 'b', 'c']
text_list = view('123')
text_list
```

shows

```
['123   more text a more text ', '123   more text b more text ', '123   more text c more text ']
```

Why? Because the string representation of a string uses `'` until there is a `'` contained in the string. Then it uses `"` for delimiting the string.

Simpler examples are

```
>>> "'"
"'"
>>> '"'
'"'
>>> "'\""
'\'"'
```

But it shouldn't make a difference. As said, this is just the string representation of a string which exists in your program. These delimiters aren't really in the string itself. See the difference between what `str()` and `repr()` do, respectively.

Comment: If I'm understanding right, that if my string text already contains ```'``` then it will force ```"```?

Comment: @paranormaldist It uses `"` as a delimiter then, yes. I wouldn't talk of "force", however.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an explanation of why this occurs, but maybe a solution: If you wrap another `str()` around your string (double or single quoted), the result should always be single quoted, at least when I tried it.